# c# namespace clash

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll

I have a c# project, where the default namespace is `Project.App` - I have another project, where the default namespace is `Project.Service`.

I'm including the DLL created from `Project.Service` as a reference in `Project.App` - The reason being the projects are in two different solutions, maintained by two different groups.

When I try to use the reference in code and compile, I'm always getting an error that says `"The type or namespace 'Service' does not exist in the namespace 'Project'".`

What am I missing here?

Edit: I found the solution to my issue: [Namespace not recognized (even though it is there)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228992/namespace-not-recognized-even-though-it-is-there)

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: How are you adding the reference?  What does the code look like?

Comment: Does the error occur on a "using" statement within Project.App?

Comment: @GameScripting: this is very basic - I'm just trying to use a class from a reference - I'm not sure what other way to try.

Comment: @David: I just right-clicked in visual studio, and added reference and pointed to the DLL

Comment: @unicron: Its fine when I add that statement. But when compiling, thats where the error is...

Comment: Right-click the reference and check the `Properties` to see if anything is odd - specifically the Aliases (`global`), Copy Local (`True`), and Specific Version (`False`).

Comment: When adding the reference, I see you are not using a Project Reference (local to the solution), and just adding the compiled .dll of the other project.  Have you tried combining them into one solution?  Also, try opening the referenced .dll in Class Explorer and see if it has the correct namespace.

Comment: I could have it as part of the solution, but its being maintained somewhere else...so I don't have access to the source code..

Answer (score 1):

[How to: Use the Namespace Alias Qualifier (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```
//example
using colAlias = System.Collections;
```

Comment: Tried that - in my case, it still says the same thing. After compiling, what it says is that "Service" doesn't exist. Its like when you say Project.[something] it is only going to the local project (which is name Project.App)

Answer (score 0):

I would check first if the reference it is really being added: maybe the target framework in the **Service** dll is different (later version) than the one in your app.

Answer (score 0):

I read an article a while back (after stylecop told me to move my using statements) that moving using statements inside the current namespace can help with namespace clashes like this.

```
namespace example
{ 
   using xxxxx
}
```

See the following post: [Should 'using' statements be inside or outside the namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125319/should-usings-be-inside-or-outside-the-namespace)

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the `Project.Service` dll an alias and then importing the alias into your code. Like this:

1. Right-click on the referenced dll in your project's References folder and click 'Properties'
2. In the Aliases field enter a new alias for this reference, something like 'Services'
3. On your code page add this directive at the top of the page: `extern alias Services;`
4. Add a using statement like this: using Service = Services;
5. Reference the `Project.Service` namespace like so: `Service.DoSomthing();`

You should be good to go at this point.

Comment: That's strange. Can you please post the code you used? This should  work. Maybe you or I missed something?

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to have reference correctly...

All classes in `Project.Service` could be `internal` so other projects will not "see" anything.

If it is true - make public OR make your assembly friend of other assembly "InternalsVisibleTo" (note that it requires both to be strongly signed).

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that the class you want to use is in the Project.Service namespace and that it is public?  Even if Project.Service is the default namespace, that doesn't guarantee that any classes in the assembly have that namespace.