# The type or namespace name 'AutoMapper' could not be found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dll, reference, .net-4.0

Hi ive got an issue very similar to this question:[Namespace not recognized (even though it is there)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228992/namespace-not-recognized-even-though-it-is-there) but their solution doesn't work for me as my project is already set up in the correct framework. So the issue I've got a reference that I have already added into the project called AutoMapper. Where I am using the correct version of this reference 4.0.4.0, https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper/4.0.4
The issue is that when I try to run the project the controllers that are using this reference aren't seeming to pick it up and causes an error saying: "The type or namespace name 'AutoMapper' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)". I've tried adding the dll file to the bin file from someone else's project, which for some reason theirs manages to work.

Comment: What version of .Net Framework is your project set to?

Comment: Currently is set up to .Net 4.0

Comment: Once I type for instance using AutoMapper; The intellisense will recognise the namespace. But once I build/run the project the issue occurs.

Comment: Is the reference set to Copy Local?

Comment: yep should it be false?

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same issue as in bellow errors

```
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'AutoMapper' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

But I have fixed it by comparing both package directory in Project folder and inside Dockerfile and finally I had found that my packages folder in my project directory containing name  **AutoMapper.2.0.1** but In Dockerfile after running **RUN nuget restore project_file_name** the packages folder containing name as **AutoMapper.2.0.1.0** so both are different then I rename the directiry **AutoMapper.2.0.1.0** to **AutoMapper.2.0.1** in Dockerfile and then **RUN dotnet restore project_file_name** it fixed in my case.