# VS2015: Cannot use a namespace from another project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015

I have two C# projects, one is a .NET Core Web (Project A) and the other a Windows Service project (project B).

I've added project A as a reference of B. Project B is the main one. For some reason, I can't see from B the namespace provided by the project A. The namespace is listed in B's `References` list. If I click on the listed reference I get this error:

[image]

What I've tried so far:

- clean + rebuild
- VS2015 restart
- Machine reboot

I'm building against the same .NET Framework 4.6.1

Comment: In the configuration manager for the configuration you are building against are they both being built?

Comment: Also check that both are using the same version of the .net framework.

Comment: @MikeCheel both are built, yes. Also, I'm building against the same .NET Framework 4.6.1

Comment: Is the platform target the same? Go through the Compile options and double check.

Comment: I'm checking, in the meantime I've added some clarifications. Please have a look. Platform target for the .NET core is Debug-AnyCPU-IISExpress

Comment: agree with @MikeCheel this sounds like you are building the two projects for different .net versions

Comment: Check this answer as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19453617/426422

Comment: Are you sure that this structure is actually correct? Generally a web specific project type is similar to an exe project (such as your service) in being at the "top" of referencing relationships, and not being used as a reference in other projects.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever not quite sure it's correct. Do you suggest to move the bulk of the .NET core project into it's own project, target a DLL and then have it referenced by both the .NET Web app project and the Windows Service?

Comment: Yes, I'd normally expect the shared code to be in some kind of class library project.